# How can we get the Prediction Percentage in Mahout Random Forest

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, weka, mahout

I am new to Mahout.

I am trying to run Random Forest algorithm.

I was trying to find out if TestForest would output the prediction percentage of individual input fed to it. I understand that it outputs the .out file which just has the predictions. But will I get as output the percentage with which it was predicted correctly(or wrongly).

I know that we do get that information in Weka.

Like:
1.0   0.96
0.0   0.514
etc

So, if someone would help me understand that in Mahout.